# Работа с id в базах данных

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, .net

Реализую базу данных магазина. Имеется БД, в которой есть 3 таблицы: таблица с информацией о товаре (описаны характеристики + стролбец с id), таблица со списоком клиентов (личные данные клиентов и id для каждого) и третья таблица - сводная. В ней идут названия магазинов и отделения в них а также id-шники клиентов и id товара, которые они купили в данных отделах.
Расскажите, пожалуйста, как в приложении C# (WinForms) с базой данных SQL Server 2008 реализуется работа с id. Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы id присваивался автоматически и всегда был уникальным числом. Конечно, можно сделать рандомные числа, но всё равно остаётся вероятность, что они совпадут, если БД большая. Может быть есть встроенные средства SQL Server для создания id ? 
P.S. не судите строго за глупость вопроса, просто не имею большого опыта работы с базами данных.

Comment: Мне вот только интересно, почему  за такой несложный вопрос наставили столько плюсов))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для MS SQL SERVER при создании таблицы для колонки ID нужно указать слово IDENTITY

```
CREATE TABLE SalePoint
(
    SalePointId int IDENTITY(1,1), -- указываем перый элемент и шаг
    SalePointName nvarchar(1000) not null
)
```

теперь при вставке колонку с id можно опускать

```
insert into SalePoint (SalePointName) values ('AAA'), ('BBB'), ('CCC')
select * from SalePoint
```

выведет

```
1  AAA
2  BBB
3  CCC
```

для получения последней вставленной id можно использовать переменную @@IDENTITY

```
select @@IDENTITY -- в этом примере вернет 3
```

ссылки

[Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775(v=sql.105).aspx)

[@@Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

**UPD(спасибо renegator):**

@@IDENTITY возвращает последний вставленный ID во всей БД. Для получения последнего ID в текущем запросе необходимо использовать ф-ю [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315(SQL.105).aspx).

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Уже по первому ответе в теме погуглил, разобрался и написал небольшой тестовый пример, а благодаря Вашему ответу, прояснил тематику до конца.

Comment: Неточный ответ. Верный результат вернет функция SCOPE_IDENTITY

Comment: Все таки уточню еще. @@IDENTITY - последний ID, вставленный транзакцией. Однако безобидный на первый взгляд оператор INSERT для некой таблицы Table1 может вызвать триггер, который также, в свою очередь, выполнит вставку в некую таблицу Table2, где есть колонка с автоинкрементом. Так вот, после выполнения такого запроса @@IDENTITY будет содержать ID из таблицы Table2. Тогда как SCOPE_IDENTITY гарантированно вернет ID из Table1

Comment: @renegator спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я помню, в SQL есть свойтсво AutoIncrement для id.

Comment: Благодарю!